# Windows Phone UIElementCollection in UserControl

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a UIElementCollection in my UserControl with custom UIElements. But the UIElements are not displayed. Whats wrong?

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildrenProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Children", typeof(UIElementCollection), typeof(MyControl), null);

    public UIElementCollection Children
    {
        get { return (UIElementCollection)GetValue(ChildrenProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ChildrenProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Children.Clear();
        UserControl child = new SecondUserControl();
        child.Measure(availableSize);
        Children.Add(child);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            child.Arrange(new Rect(0,0, child.DesiredSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Height));
        }
        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any xaml to go with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oy vey. Whatever it is you're trying to do, that isn't the way to do it.

First, your Children colleciton never makes it to the UI. Just declaring properties and measuring stuff doesn't actually add it to the UI. You have to make sure the children are part of the visual tre by adding them to something on the UserControl.Content.

Second, why are you adding and removing children on every Measure pass? That doesn't make sense for any usecase. The Measure & arrange pass isn't a time to remove/add control, it's a time to measure and arrange control.

Comment: I now the codes make no sense. It was only an example. Is there no possibility to add further UI elements to visual tree? Adapted I use a derived class of FrameworkElement. How can I add further childs to the visual tree? There is no Content property. Or I am forced to use a panel or usercontrol?

Comment: If you're creating a custom control you should add a new style to the Themes/Generic.xaml file and create a visual tree for your custom control. If you're creating a user control you'll have access to UserControl.Content or items nested therein.